# Laravel + Google Cloud Messaging (Connection timed out)

Tags: android, laravel, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am using Laravel as Backend server for my android application.
Here is the package I used for sending push messages: https://packagist.org/packages/davibennun/laravel-push-notification

I made all settings (server-side + client-side) and gave it a try. 
It sends messages without any issue, except sometime it gives me a timeout error:

> Zend \ Http \ Client \ Adapter \ Exception \ RuntimeException 
>   Unable to connect to android.googleapis.com:443 . Error #0: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to android.googleapis.com:443 (Connection timed out)

What should i do to make it reliable? I want to make sure that message is sent to the app.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same error and trying to figure it out why.

There are some possibility for this error.

1. Your internet firewall block the connection to the google : pls try 
   `ping android.googleapis.com` in your laravel host. or `curl -v gcm-http.googleapis.com` if doesn't response then it is blocked.
2. Open your the port for google api to work, I open the port usually `443` , `5528-2230`. you might configure in your firewall
3. the `gcm-http.googleapis.com` has a lot of ip addresses, so you need to allow connection from these ip addresses this is one of their ip address : `172.217.3.170`. **mine solve the problem by allowing the connection between the range of their ip addresses**. you can monitor the ip address in your firewall software.
4. you can find the range of google api IP addresses [here](http://whois.domaintools.com/172.217.24.234) and [here](http://whois.domaintools.com/216.58.196.202)

it depends on your firewall configuration you need to setup those with the guy who configure the firewall since I assume you work in the secure network environment.