# Failed to connect to www.googleapis.com port 443: Network unreachable

Tags: php, symfony, google-signin, google-client

I'm trying to implement google sign-in in my website that is written in Symfony2 using [Google Client API](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client). I followed the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/server-side-flow), but when I call $client->authenticate($code); command an exception is thrown telling that:
 Failed to connect to www.googleapis.com port 443: Network unreachable 
What is the problem?

Comment: check your firewalre configuration plesae see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/39590519/2652524

Answer (score 7):

Solution 2 (from update).
it seems to be some bug with ipv6 interfaces and curl with php, so another solution is to set the appropiate option in curl function to connect to the remote server with ipv4 in your php script

curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);

---

Solution 1.

The same happened to me (**solved by adding the ip v4 and hostname to /etc/hosts file**), As pointed by @hans-z in another answer comment, I tried using next command to validate the network issue.

```
curl -v https://www.googleapis.com
```

It turned out that it was randomly, and only 1 in 10 tries the curl command could connect to the server, the response was something like:
("La red es inaccesible" means in english "network unreachable" :) )

```
$ curl -v https://www.googleapis.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.googleapis.com/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 64.233.186.95...
*   Trying 2800:3f0:4003:c00::5f...
* connect to 2800:3f0:4003:c00::5f port 443 failed: La red es inaccesible
* Failed to connect to www.googleapis.com port 443: La red es inaccesible
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to www.googleapis.com port 443: La red es inaccesible
```

And the successfull response was:

```
curl -v https://www.googleapis.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.googleapis.com/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 64.233.186.95...
*   Trying 2800:3f0:4003:c00::5f...
* Connected to www.googleapis.com (64.233.186.95) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* Server certificate:
*    subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Mountain View; O=Google Inc; CN=*.storage.googleapis.com
*    start date: 2015-04-08 14:12:01 GMT
*    expire date: 2015-07-07 00:00:00 GMT
*    subjectAltName: www.googleapis.com matched
*    issuer: C=US; O=Google Inc; CN=Google Internet Authority G2
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: www.googleapis.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
< Date: Tue, 21 Apr 2015 21:38:12 GMT
< Vary: X-Origin
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
* Server GSE is not blacklisted
< Server: GSE
< Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=1
< Accept-Ranges: none
< Vary: Origin,Accept-Encoding
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
* Connection #0 to host www.googleapis.com left intact
```

The weird message was "Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache", I was using google DNS's 4.4.4.4 and 8.8.8.8, so I added that domain to my /etc/hosts file using the ipv4 from the curl command output and the problem was solved.

```
#/etc/hosts
...
64.233.186.95 www.googleapis.com
#DONT COPY THIS IP, USE THE ONE FROM YOUR CURL OUTPUT
...
```

Comment: This immediately resolved the timeout issues I was having while trying to connect to the **Google GCM API** from my local development - MAMP with Apache/2.2.29, PHP 5.6.10 and curl 7.41.0. 

What's weird is that not all requests were timing out. Many did though.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like an outgoing firewall/proxy/network issue. You should be able to verify that using `ping` and `curl` from the machine where your website runs.

Comment: I am testing it on localhost. Is this the problem?

Comment: I tried it with my VPS and it prints an 404 Not Found response.

Comment: Even when I type the url in my computer it brings a page with a string : Not Found. But there was no problem with my friends PC.

Comment: When I type the url in browser most of the times it brings me Not Found and rarely it redirects to https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl

Comment: I tested curl in my VPS because I am developing in windows.

Comment: it happens to me too. from my local network sometimes (randomly) it resolves the host, using the curl command sometines y get:

* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 64.233.186.95...
*   Trying 2800:3f0:4003:c00::5f...
* Connected to www.googleapis.com (64.233.186.95) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs ... 

and sometimes error: 

connect to 2800:3f0:4003:c00::5f port 443 failed: The network is inaccessible
* Failed to connect to www.googleapis.com port 443: The network is inaccessible
* Closing connection 0

Comment: to check if this is a firewall issue try `telnet android.googleapis.com 443` from your server..

Answer (score 3):

If your network under proxy. You should set the proxy url and port

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "http://url.com"); //your proxy url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, "80"); // your proxy port number
```

This is solves my problem

Answer (score 1):

Try this echo ipv4 >> ~/.curlrc.
It Worked for me.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer!

Comment: Sorry Div I was not be able to comment that is why I answered

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue - problem was with dns resolution, like mentioned in le0diaz's answer.

On ubuntu 16.04, we were able to solve it by chaning /etc/gai.conf, changing the presedance for IPv6, uncommenting the following line:
precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100