# Failed to connect to www.googleapis.com port 443: Network is unreachable

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, youtube-data-api

I'm Using this library to get a feed of videos and livestreams from Youtube from a wordpress site. 
https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

The code was working ok for the past month but suddenly it started to get Failed to connect errors randomly (2 in 10 attempts comes failed, the others goes just fine)

This is the code from where im getting the error:

```
function googleapis_get_live_event_widget(){

    //Youtube Videos and Live Events
    require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/lib/google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php' );
    $GOOGLE_DEVELOPER_KEY = get_field('cce_api_google_developer_key','option');

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setDeveloperKey($GOOGLE_DEVELOPER_KEY);
    $youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

    try {
        $islive = get_field('cce_live_event','option');

        $opts = array();
        $opts['channelId'] = get_field('cce_api_youtube_channel_id','option');
        if($islive) {
            $opts['eventType'] = 'live';
        }
        $opts['type'] = 'video';
        $opts['maxResults'] = 1;
        $opts['order'] = 'date';


        $live_videos = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet',$opts);

        $data = array();
        $data['live_events'] = $live_videos;
        echo Timber::compile('partials/live_event_widget.twig',$data);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $error = array();
        $error['message'] = $e->getMessage();
        echo Timber::compile('partials/error.twig',$error);
        return;
    }


}

add_shortcode('googleapis_live_widget','googleapis_get_live_event_widget');
```

doing a  `curl -v https://www.googleapis.com` via ssh in the server results in this when is a failed attempt:

```
[~]# curl -v https://www.googleapis.com
* About to connect() to www.googleapis.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 216.58.216.202... Connection timed out
*   Trying 2607:f8b0:4009:80b::200a... Failed to connect to     2607:f8b0:4009:80b::200a: Network is unreachable
* Success
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 2607:f8b0:4009:80b::200a: Network is unreachable
```

And like this when the request is good:

```
curl -v https://www.googleapis.com
* About to connect() to www.googleapis.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 216.58.216.106... connected
* Connected to www.googleapis.com (216.58.216.106) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
* Server certificate:
*   subject: CN=*.googleapis.com,O=Google Inc,L=Mountain View,ST=California,C=US
*   start date: Oct 21 22:31:24 2015 GMT
*   expire date: Jan 19 00:00:00 2016 GMT
*   common name: *.googleapis.com
*   issuer: CN=Google Internet Authority G2,O=Google Inc,C=US
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.19.1 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: www.googleapis.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
< Date: Sat, 31 Oct 2015 11:33:49 GMT
< Vary: X-Origin
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Server: GSE
< Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=1
< Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; p="1"; ma=604800
< Accept-Ranges: none
< Vary: Origin,Accept-Encoding
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
* Connection #0 to host www.googleapis.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

At this moment if i run the page the feeds are displayed normally.

What should i be looking for fixing the inconsistency?

Comment: I assume you have problem because of your firewall see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/39590519/2652524

Comment: Thanks, the problem was solved via adjusting the firewall settings allowing the range of IPs Google uses.

Comment: please give up vote to the answer if that useful, that would be greatly appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 5):

I've got the same error and trying to figure it out why.

There are some possibility for this error.

1. Your internet firewall block the connection to the google : pls try 
   `ping android.googleapis.com` in your laravel host. or `curl -v gcm-http.googleapis.com` if doesn't response then it is blocked.
2. Open your the port for google api to work, I open the port usually `443` , `5528-2230`. you might configure in your firewall
3. the `gcm-http.googleapis.com` has a lot of ip addresses, so you need to allow connection from these ip addresses this is one of their ip address : `172.217.3.170`. **mine solve the problem by allowing the connection between the range of their ip addresses**. you can monitor the ip address in your firewall software.
4. you can find the range of google api IP addresses [here](http://whois.domaintools.com/172.217.24.234) and [here](http://whois.domaintools.com/216.58.196.202)

it depends on your firewall configuration you need to setup those with the guy who configure the firewall since I assume you work in the secure network environment.

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue with one of my users trying to access the Google Drive api.
Finally it was due to the app not being allowed to access the internet. So, he finally granted that permission for my app in his device and everything started to work again.